# Why cannot I get parent variable in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Code:

```
class A {
    public $arrayToReturn = array();
    function __construct() {
        $arrayToReturn['country'] = 'US';
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function foo() {
        print_r($arrayToReturn);
   }
}
$b = new B();
$b->foo();
print_r($b->arrayToReturn);
```

Result:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: arrayToReturn in xxxx.php on line 11
Array
(
)
```

I cannot get array in functions of class B, and get an empty array which should has one element by $b->arrayToReturn call. Why?

Comment: flagged as "why this code is not working". please give more details.

Comment: and then of course, also dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `$this->arrayToReturn`:

```
class B extends A {
    public function foo() {
        print_r($this->arrayToReturn);
   }
}
```

Same in class A:

```
class A {
    public $arrayToReturn = array();
    function __construct() {
        $this->arrayToReturn['country'] = 'US';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my first problem. But the array was added one element in the parent constructor, why did I get an empty array?

Comment: Look at the duplicate. _Why aren't parent constructors being called?_

Comment: @sxlllslgh you have to create constructor in your class B also and call `parent::__construct();` from it, then you will have it ;) Good luck

Comment: @pavlovich Yeah now I understand it.Thanks a lot.:)